# Facebook post a message on a wall without open a dialog

Tags: android, facebook

I would like to post a message on the wall
this line works:
***mFacebook.dialog(FacebookActivity.this, "post", new SampleDialogListener());***

But i would like to post a message without open a dialog i tried this but get error which says mFacebook.request parameter mismatch

***response = mFacebook.request("me/feed", parameters, "POST");***

Comment: What are the parameters you use for the *request* method? Also, have you asked for the "publish_stream" permission?

Comment: 'parameters mismatch' means the error has to do with your parameters variable. Please show code for how your add the params to your parameters Bundle.

Answer (score 1):

To post to a wall without a dialog you have to use the graph-api. Perform a feed post onto/with the userId of the target. To perform the Post you will have to need the publish_stream permission of the user. The returned accessToken of the permission-request has to be one of the post-parameters.

Answer (score 0):

```
String response = mFacebook.request(Id+"/feed",bundle,HTTP_METHOD_POST);
```

But you have to check login before calling this method.Because it cannot check for login.
the code to login and it is single sign on.

```
mFacebook.authorize(this, PERMISSIONS, Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH, new ABCDialogListener());
```

and code to check session valid or not by

mFacebook.isSessionValid() method